# Formatting unicode characters

Tags: java, android, unicode, string-formatting

I am getting string in following format-

```
\"When you\u2019re riding, only the race in which you\u2019re riding is important.\u201D
```

where `\u2019` is for single quote

and `\"` and  `\u201D` is for right and left double quote.

I want to format it such that it displays properly like-

```
"When you're riding, only the race in which you're riding is important."
```

How can i do that?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I am getting above displayed string `fromString(string.getBytes(), "UTF-8");`..now i want to convert it to proper format..??

Comment: Apache commons have [`unscapeJava()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) which should handle your case. However: Are there really unicode escape sequences in your string or are the characters merely displayed as such, i.e. is `you\u2019re` really 11 characters?

Comment: @dhke unicode characters are displayed as shown above in the question..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
try
{
    String s = new String("\"When you\u2019re riding, only the race in which you\u2019re riding is important.\u201D".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
}
```

Comment: same result.. `\"When you\u2019re riding, only the race in which you\u2019re riding is important.\u201D`